# tezos estimate transfer error

Tags: transfer

We are getting issue while calling Tezos.estimate.transfer function , it gives 'Unauthorized'
error.  I have attached a screenshot as well.
Here are code shown below:
If we run below code with custom node url ,then it throws an Unauthorized error.
Its working fine with public node url
image-A(attached)
Here are the error we are getting with custom node:
error:  HttpResponse: Http error response: (401)
at HttpBackend. (/home/ant/Downloads/tezos-test/node_modules/@taquito/http-utils/dist/taquito-http-utils.umd.js:480:31)
at Generator.throw ()
at rejected (/home/ant/Downloads/tezos-test/node_modules/@taquito/http-utils/dist/taquito-http-utils.umd.js:30:69)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
status: 401,
statusText: 'Unauthorized',
body: '',[image]

Comment: Hi Ashwani, are you currently running a sandbox at a specific endpoint? or are you using a public testnet/ mainnet?

Comment: on mainnet, I think i need to add some tags in config.json but not know about that tags. that i missed

Comment: Is this a Private node for mainnet? Could it be that the node's settings are blocking the request? it seems like this is a connection error rather than a estimation error since its seen as unauthorized